# How to resize google maps marker? Javascript

Tags: javascript, maps, markers

This question has been answered before, however when I implement the stated solution it does not work for me. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated:)

```
  function geolocateFunc(){
    GMaps.geolocate({
      success: function(position) {
        map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        map.addMarker({
          icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(150, 150),
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
          infoWindow: {content: "<strong>This is my current location</strong>"},
        });     
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert('Geolocation failed: '+error.message);
      },
      not_supported: function() {
        alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
      },
      always: function() {
        alert("Done!");
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried the scaledSize function and it does not see to work

Comment: did you try copying the `blue-dot.png` to your computer and resizing it, then uploading it to your own server, or do you absolutely need to do it programmatically? keep in mind doing it manually is a lot more efficient than doing ti with JS on every execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating a new Marker rather than the addMarker method. If still no joy see if the "optimized" attribute setting makes adifference

Courtesy w3schools: -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850); 
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 5};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas,mapOptions);
  var pinkball = {size: new google.maps.Size(100, 100),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(100, 100),
                    url: "pinkball.png"};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    icon: pinkball
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>
<!--
To use this code on your website, get a free API key from Google.
Read more at: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_basic.asp
-->

</body>
</html>
```